# DropDown box with Numbers in PowerApps

Tags: excel, dropdown, powerapp, datasource

I am trying to create  drop down box in PowerApps that will have the numbers from 1 to 10. I want a user to select a number and the next screen would have the x amount of rows the user picked. so they can fill in data.

I've created a table named NumOfDocs with a column called DocNum and it has a list starting from 1 down to 10. I added the data source to PowerApps and used the formula `Distinct(NumOfDocs, DocNum)` but I get an error that reads:

> The property expects a Number value, but this rule produces incompatible Table values.

I'm new to PowerApps and not sure why I'm getting this error. I looked up everywhere online but could only find examples of strings and not numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it works like this. I've created a data source as you said.

[image]

[image]